# Why do breadcrumbs just show "Home"?

Tags: theming, 8, breadcrumbs

Do breadcrumbs show by default in Drupal 8? I have created nodes, added them to the menu, and made some parent child relationships in the main menu. The breadcrumb in Bartik only shows 'Home'. Is there a trick or config to flag to get the breadcrumbs to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like 'path' is required.. maybe it's always been like this and I just didn't realize. Installing Pathauto (from GitHub) and Token (from Drupal.org) corrects the issue.